# django-tables2: Better way of avoiding capital letters in table head

Tags: django-templates, django-tables2

Somewhat closely related to [this](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/475), I do not want my table head to have capital letters at the start (Django default).

I already know I could do it with a `render` method, but is there something simpler? My code so far:

```
class ProductTable(tables2.Table):

    _name = tables2.Column(accessor="name", verbose_name = "serial")
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        sequence = ("_name",)
        exclude = ("name",)
```

Comment: Are you seeing that column header "serial" getting capitalized and showing "Serial"? Does the Product class have a field named serial? I'm using DT2 v.2.3.1 and whatever I have in `verbose_name="lower case col name"` stays in that case and isn't capitalized or titlecased.

Comment: You refer to the model with your `verbose_name = ...` right?

Comment: Yes, I use the `verbose_name="asdf"` in many places, and I just checked, if I put it all in lowercase, it's showing up in lowercase in the UI.